Isomorphic extension of a $C^*$ algebra by compact operators
Let $A,E,E'$ be $C^*$-algebras and $K(H),K(H')$ be two $C^*$-algebras of compact operators on separable and infinite-dimensional Hilbert spaces $H,H'$.
Consider the diagram
$$\require{AMScd}\begin{CD}
 0 @>>> K(H) @>>> E @>>> A @>>> 0\\
{} @V{\alpha}VV @V{\beta}VV @| {} \\
0 @>>> K(H') @>>> E' @>>{\pi'}> A @>>> 0
\end{CD}$$
where the rows are exact. Suppose $\alpha$ is a $*$-isomorphism. If there is an $*$-isomorphism $\beta$ such that the diagram commutes, I want to show that such $\beta$ is unique.
Suppose there are $*$-isomorphisms $\beta,\tilde{\beta}:E\to E'$ such that the diagram commutes. Clearly we have $\pi'(\beta(e)-\tilde{\beta}(e))=0$; however I cannot proceed further.
This is part of the remark 2.5.3 in Higson and Roe's Analytic K-Homology.

Note that $\gamma = \beta'^{-1} \circ \beta$ is an automorphism of $E$ s.t. $\gamma|_{K(H)} = \text{Id}_{K(H)}$ and $e - \gamma(e) \in K(H)$ for all $e \in E$. It suffices to show that this implies $\gamma = \text{Id}_E$.
Pick an irreducible representation $\phi: E \to B(K)$ s.t. $\phi|_{K(H)} \neq 0$. Now, we have $\phi|_{K(H)}$ is an irreducible representation of $K(H)$, as otherwise there exists $k \in K$ s.t. $\phi(K(H))k \neq \{0\}, K$, but then as $K(H) \subset E$ is an ideal, $\phi(K(H))k$ would be a nontrivial subspace of $K$ that is invariant under $\phi(E)$, contradicting irreducibility of $\phi$. But all irreducible representations of $K(H)$ are unitarily conjugate to the identity representation, so we may assume, WLOG, that $K = H$ and $\phi|_{K(H)} = \text{Id}_{K(H)}$.
But then, we have, for any unit vectors $\xi, \eta \in H$, $e \in E$,
$$\begin{split}
\langle\xi|\phi(e)|\eta\rangle|\xi\rangle\langle\eta| &= |\xi\rangle\langle\xi|\phi(e)|\eta\rangle\langle\eta| &\\
&= \phi(|\xi\rangle\langle\xi|)\phi(e)\phi(|\eta\rangle\langle\eta|) \;\;\;\;\;\; &, \text{ as }\phi|_{K(H)} = \text{Id}_{K(H)}\\
&= \phi(|\xi\rangle\langle\xi|e|\eta\rangle\langle\eta|) &\\
&= \phi \circ \gamma(|\xi\rangle\langle\xi|e|\eta\rangle\langle\eta|) &, \text{ as }K(H) \subset E\text{ is an ideal and }\gamma|_{K(H)} = \text{Id}_{K(H)}\\
&= \phi \circ \gamma(|\xi\rangle\langle\xi|)\phi \circ \gamma(e)\phi \circ \gamma(|\eta\rangle\langle\eta|) &\\
&= |\xi\rangle\langle\xi|\phi \circ \gamma(e)|\eta\rangle\langle\eta| &, \text{ as }\gamma|_{K(H)} = \text{Id}_{K(H)}\text{ and }\phi|_{K(H)} = \text{Id}_{K(H)}\\
&= \langle\xi|\phi \circ \gamma(e)|\eta\rangle|\xi\rangle\langle\eta| &
\end{split}$$
Thus, $\langle\xi|\phi(e)|\eta\rangle = \langle\xi|\phi \circ \gamma(e)|\eta\rangle$. Since this holds for all $\xi, \eta$, we have $\phi(e) = \phi \circ \gamma(e)$, i.e., $\phi(e - \gamma(e)) = 0$. But $e - \gamma(e) \in K(H)$ and $\phi|_{K(H)} = \text{Id}_{K(H)}$, so $e - \gamma(e) = 0$. As this holds for all $e \in E$, we have $\gamma = \text{Id}_E$, as desired.

By using Kadison’s transitivity theorem and slightly altering the above proof, it is not hard to see that the result still holds if $K(H)$ is replaced by any primitive $C^\ast$-algebra $B$ (i.e., $B$ admits a faithful irreducible representation).

Inspired by Gao's proof above (which is a bit hard for me), I came up with a proof.
Denote the maps $\iota:K(H)\to E$ and similarly $\iota':K(H')\to E'$.
Let $e\in E$ be arbitrary, we want to prove that $\beta(e)=\tilde{\beta}(e)$. Since the right part of the diagram commutes, we have $\pi'(\beta(e)-\tilde{\beta}(e))=0$. By the exactness of the bottom row, there is $k'\in K(H')$ such that $\iota'(k')=\beta(e)-\tilde{\beta}(e)$. We show that $k'=0$. Since $\alpha$ is an isomorphism, it suffices to show that $k'\alpha(k)=0$ for all $k\in K(H)$ (this step is inspired by Gao's proof above.) Indeed
$$
\begin{align*}
\iota' (k'\alpha(k))&=\beta(e)\iota'(\alpha(k))-\tilde{\beta}(e)\iota'(\alpha(k)) \\
&= \beta(e)\beta(\iota(k)) - \tilde{\beta}(e)\tilde{\beta}(\iota(k))\\
&=\beta(e\iota(k)) - \tilde{\beta}(e\iota(k))
\end{align*}
$$
The last expression is zero since $e\iota(k)$ lies in the ideal. Since $\iota'$ is injective, then $k'\alpha(k)=0$.
